# systemd - How can you find out whether the service was started on booting or by "systemctl restart ..."?

Tags: systemd

I wrote a service that has to behave differently, depending on whether it is started after a boot or by the command "systemctl restart ...".
Can I find out that in the daemon itself? Or alternatively set an environment variable in the "daemon.service" file for the daemon?
At the moment I don't see how this can be decided e.g. from the environment.

Thanks in advance,

Poldi

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What is the real difference? Can't you check for that difference? And what about other reasons for your service to start?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,
stupid question. I just have to write a temporary file to a ram disk ;-)

Comment: Please provide details, if only to prevent more people from posting non-answers to ask for them. The fact that people do shows by the way that your own perception of the usefulness of your question is somewhat off. ;-)

Comment: Correct, that's exactly why I apologized ;-))
And the solution was as simple as I described in my self-given answer.
My apologies again, but I dug too deep into details at the time ("stackoverflow") ;-)